Last user on a google cloud bucket, with limited rights
I'm "the last" activated user account of a company-own bucket that closed recently. As part of the closure, I'm in charge to back-up the data stored in this bucket. (important note: I'm legally authorized to do so).
I'm not able to download this data because of right limitations (gsutils is returning:)
AccessDeniedException: 403 HttpError accessing
[...]
The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state closed

Of course, I can navigate into the bucket and see all the data in there, but can't download not open. Getting Additional permissions required to view this object's metadata: Ask an object owner to grant you 'storage.objects.get' permission. 
According to IAM & Admin panel, I'm a viewer, so that explains it. Now, the only other user is 53xxxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
I basically can't do anything like changing rights or even create a billing account. Basically stuck. (Basic plan as the company stopped paying the bill)
So it is obviously an access right problems. What are my options here ?
Resolution attemps:

Run a gs-utils -m cp -r -c gs://blabla .
Isolate to smaller folder
Download directly from the web portal (GCP console)
Investigating on my own access rights in IAM & Admin
Contacting the former admin (no accesses anymore)
Trying to contact GCP support (but Basic plan, no direct support)


Does anyone has permissions at a folder or organisational level?

I suspect the former director of IT has. Trying to reach out 6 months after the closure :)
